# Confusion about setting a optional variable

Tags: swift

I want to add the option for a user to add their phone number. If they add any phone number I want to add an alert informing them if they have not added a valid 10 digit phone number. However if they do not add anything in the phone number field I want the phoneInput variable to be set to "0". How would I go about doing this.

```
var phoneInput = ""

func signUp(){
    if profileImage.image == nil {
        showAvatarError()
    } else if phoneNumber.text == "" {
        self.phoneInput = "0"
    } else if (phoneNumber.text?.characters.count)! != 10 {
        showphoneNumberError()
    }else if email.text == "" {
        showEmailError()
    }else if isValid(email.text!) != true{
      showEmailError()
    } else{
        submitPressed()
        print("Set info")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but I have to challenge your assumptions: Some, probably most, phone numbers are 10 digits. People have extensions, local phone numbers (inferred area code), various country/region codes, etc.

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted (besides being in Swift 3 and not in Swift 4)?

Comment: the problem is that the error shows because if user doesn't input a phone number the error that it does not contain 10 digits still shows.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you get the result that you do but here is a cleaner version

```
var phoneInput = ""

func signUp(){
    // This check doesn't have anything to do with the number, so separe it
    if profileImage.image == nil {
        showAvatarError()
        return
    }
    guard let temp = planEndValue.text else {
        return
    }
    let userInput = temp.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    if userInput.count == 0 {
        self.phoneInput = "0"
    } else if userInput.count != 10 {
        showphoneNumberError()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but nothing else runs if userInput is 0